# Using powershell to transform CSV file

Tags: powershell

I have CSV files which have a lot of columns. I need to transform several columns, for example, some date columns have text string of "Missing" and I want to replace "Missing" to an empty string, etc.

The following code may work but it will be a long file since there are a lot of columns. Is it a better way to write it?

```
Import-Csv $file | 
  select @( 
      @{l="xxx"; e={ ....}}, 
      # repeat many times for each column....
  ) | export-Csv
```

Comment: Does your file not have a header line?

Comment: Yes, the csv files have header.

Comment: You could use a command line find and replace tool like `FNR.EXE` to do this on the command line and it might be quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an imperative style rather than a pipelined style:

```
$records = Import-Csv $file

foreach ($record in $records) 
{
    if ($record.Date -eq 'Missing')
    {
        $record.Date = ''
    }
}

$records | Export-Csv $file
```

**Edit:** To use a pipelined style, you could do it like this:

```
import-csv $file | 
   select -ExcludeProperty Name1,Name2 -Property *,@{n='Name1'; e={"..."}},@{n='Name2'; e={'...'}}
```

The `*` is a wildcard that matches all properties. I couldn't find a way to format this code in a nicer way, so it is kind of ugly looking.

Comment: I think this approach might not be ideal since the op mentions there could be many columns with dates that need to be addressed. This would still work though.

Comment: @Matt, I though he just meant he didn't want to have to specify all the unaltered columns in the code.

Comment: Will pipeline be more efficient since it may not need to read the whole csv file in memory? The drawback is it may change the order of the columns (also it doesn't matter in my case).

Comment: @dc7a9163d9, the pipelined one will be more memory-efficient, yes. But that wouldn't matter unless the files were huge.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is a find-replace, you don't really need to read it as a CSV.

You could do this instead:

```powershell
Get-Content $file | %{$_.ToString().Replace("Missing", "")} | Out-File $file
```

Comment: You should probably change you output file to be different as your input file when you have them connected in the same pipe as you have. Either that or you break the pipe and save the input data into a variable which you then output on a different line.

Comment: @Matt - Can you clarify what you mean?